# How to get JSON data from url in Node.js with Express

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am trying to get the a Json object from a url using Express:

this is my code:

```
app.get('/device/:id', (req, res, next) => {
     console.log('device: ' + req.params.id + ' Request received');
     let parsedContent = JSON.parse(req.query);
     //res.status(201).send('success');
 });
```

this my url:

```
http://localhost:4001/device/1?{"type":"fridge","pcb"=2.4}
```

I get an error on the parsing line.

Here is the error as requested:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
  at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I have also tried this:

```
app.get('/device/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    let query = url.parse(req.url).query;
    if( query ) {
        let parsedContent = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(query));
    }
});
```

With this url:

```
http://localhost:4001/device/1??type=fridge&pcb=2.4
```

Still the same issue.

Comment: could you add more information and what error you get

Comment: Also it is device and not dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send json data in request, it is better to make use of `POST` request. Then the server should accept post data.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));

...

app.post('/device/:id', (req, res, next) => {
   console.log('device: ' + req.params.id + ' Request received');
   let parsedContent = JSON.parse(req.query);
   let payload = req.body.payload; // your json data
   //res.status(201).send('success');
});
```

if you insist on using `GET` request, you need to urlencode the query parameters before sending it to the server.

`http://localhost:4001/device/1?payload=%7B%22type%22%3A%22fridge%22%2C%22pcb%22%3D2.4%7D`

In your server code, you can access it as `let payload = JSON.parse(req.query.payload)`

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. I think I like your approach more.

Comment: downvote: POST has deferent semantic. Also consider caching / proxy handling.

Comment: @l00k Why? The answer contains methods to use in both `POST` and `GET`. Also why introduce things that OP doesn't require. You could always add to the answer if you have any points.

Answer (score 1):

Your url should be :

```
http://localhost:4001/device/1?type=fridge&pcb=2.4
```

You can't write a query as you did in your url. It has to follow the format.

? depicts the start of the query. Then you put the key value pair as key=value and if you have many of them then use single &

So `?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3` ....

Your req.query will be :

```
{"type":"fridge","pcb"=2.4}
```

Comment: hello, and thanks for the quick reply. I need to send a Json object in json format. this is meant to be a http request not a not url.

Comment: If you pass it this way you do get your object as a json